# Drawable.toBitmap returning a blank Bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I would like to get a custom size Bitmap from a Drawable with the least amount of code as possible.

I have a working solution here:

```
                    if (drawable != null) {
                        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, artWidth, artHeight)
                        val bitmapDrawable: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                artWidth,
                                artHeight,
                                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                        )
                        val canvas = Canvas(bitmapDrawable)
                        val paint = Paint()
                        paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorPrimary)
                        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, artWidth.toFloat(), artHeight.toFloat(), paint)
                        drawable.draw(canvas)
                        imageViewArt.setImageBitmap(bitmapDrawable)
                    }
```

This is fine and I can pass parameters to a method that does this.

I found a supposedly simpler solution that uses the following code.

```
                    drawable?.let { d ->
                        imageViewArt.setImageBitmap(d.toBitmap(artWidth, artWidth))
                    }
```

This is the Drawable I am testing with [image: This is the Drawable I am testing with]

This is the Bitmap returned from d.toBitmap(artWidth, artWidth) [image: This is the Bitmap returned from d.toBitmap(artWidth, artWidth)]

Here is the VectorDrawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:pathData="M12,3v10.55c-0.59,-0.34 -1.27,-0.55 -2,-0.55 -2.21,0 -4,1.79 -4,4s1.79,4 4,4 4,-1.79 4,-4V7h4V3h-6z"
      android:fillColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The `toBitmap()` extension is pretty much the same, functionally, as your first snippet, except that it will not do the `drawRect()` with `colorPrimary`, which is basically just adding a background. It's not really clear what you're seeing, or how exactly you're viewing it (gray background image on a gray background viewer?) but that would be the first thing I'd investigate.

Comment: The drawable is black, and yea, it's a grey image on the grey background.

Comment: I do not know why the black drawable is not rendered onto the Bitmap.

Comment: Are you certain it's black? I mean, is that the exact image file you're using in your project? Or is that just a screenshot of the actual image? Does the real image possibly have transparency? Is it an xml or vector image? Or is it a bmp/png/jpg/etc.?

Comment: It's a black VectorDrawable. I added the code.

Comment: I just ran a quick test with that vector drawable, and it works as expected for me. Possibly something else going wrong in your actual setup. Are you using that particular drawable resource anywhere else in your code? If so, are you tinting or filtering it somehow?

Comment: I think the problem is the background, and the debugger showing the Bitmap wrong, because it works as expected in other places in my project.